# How do I print a string using a for loop but with no spaces?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose we have 'My dog is blue', it prints it with spaces. I have tried using the sep, but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried other methods as well such as .replace(' ', '')

```
N = input()

for i in N:
    print(i, sep = '')
```

Comment: the easy way is just `print("My dog is Blue".replace(" ","")`  or  `print(N.replace(" ","")`. Your for-loop print each individual character per line, if you want to avoid a  a particular character, you need to remove it first with a replace or with a check with an `if`

Comment: additionally print can take another keyword argument `end` that is the last character to print, the default value is newline `\n`... `sep` is the character to put between `A` and `B` when you do `print(A,B)`

Comment: Yes, it needs to print each individual character per line, but when I do `print(N.replace(" ",""))` it doesn't seem to print each individual character per line.

Comment: the `print(N.replace(" ",""))` is to print without spaces that you mention in the tittle. If you goal is to print each individual character per line, your code does exactly that, what is wrong with it? what is your desire output? maybe what you want is `for i in N.replace(" ",""): print(i)`

Comment: show us an example of your desire output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sep` parameter defines the character inserted in between each fields of a same print:

```
print('a', 'b', 4, sep='tutu')
>>> 'atutubtutu4'
```

If you don't want a default '\n' to be inserted at the end, just use the `end` parameter and set it to the empty string

```
print('a', end='')
```

The documentation is here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

What didn't worked with `.replace(' ', '')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
for i in N.replace(" ",""): print(i)
```